# Reliable mobile provider on the train from Utrecht to Eindhoven?

Tags: trains, netherlands, mobile-operators, phone-networks

Let me be more specific. I'm traveling often by train from Utrecht to Eindhoven. I use my phone with Vodafone subscription but apparently it has a dead spot somewhere close to Den Bosch and Eindhoven.

Do you have any suggestion how to achieve a more stable connection?

P.S. I know that I'm in iron moving object that makes it harder

Comment: Have you tried sending an email to Vodafone customer support?

Comment: Sure! The answer was "you're in fast-moving iron object, so expect issues with connection"

Comment: Well, that non-answer alone is a good reason to cancel your Vodafone subscription. I got the answer that I should "not expect any improvement of the network in these spots [between Düren and Aachen] in the near future" and that "it is not currently planned to add base stations to local trains".

Comment: That is why I put a question here

Comment: @Alexander I'm pretty sure there are plenty of legal issues that prevent a Dutch cell provider from putting their cell towers on German land... unless you're talking about Vodafone Germany. It'd be nice if all the Vodafone subsidiaries played nicely with each other, of course – but they don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the (4G) coverage maps (dekkingsgebeid / dekkingskaart) of the Dutch network providers here: http://www.4gdekking.nl

Have you tried switching to 2G or 3G? Or maybe KPN's coverage is a bit better – their coverage map looks more solid, but the best way to find out for sure is to buy a prepaid SIM and test it.